# Is there a natural square root for a path of operators?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, matrix-calculus, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Suppose you have a smooth path of invertible operators $t \rightarrow A(t) $ such that $A(0) = Id$. Is there a way of defining a natural square root $X(t)$ such that the following identity holds ? 
$$\forall t, X(t)^2 = A(t)$$

Some observations:

-In my problem I can't have any assumption on spectrum of $A(t)$ globaly. Because of continuity, we only know that, for small enough $\epsilon$, the spectrum of $A(t+\epsilon)A(t)^{-1}$ is in the circle $\sigma \in \mathbb{C}, |\sigma-1|<1$

-If $A(t)$ are just numbers or if they are matrices that commutes with each others we have such a result. For exemple the following system define a natural square root associated to the path.

$$ X(0) = 0, \partial_t X(t) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_t A(t)A(t)^{-1}X(t) $$

However I want to deal with the case in which there is, in general, no commutation relation at different times ( $A(t)A(t') \neq A(t')A(t)$). And in the general case, I think that the previous formula fails to define a square root (or at least I'm not able to prove it)

-The operators I deal with are in general self-adjoint/unitary or both. So if we need to assume that kind of hypothesis in order to obtain a result, this would not be a big deal for me.

-For me this relation seems to be linked with the existence of a natural logarithm associated to the same path $e^{Y_t}=A(t)$. Because if it exists, then $X_t= e^{\frac{1}{2}Y_t}$ would be a square root.

Comment: To the OP. On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that when $t\in (a,b)$,

i) $A(t)\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $C^k,C^{\infty}$ or analytic.

ii) $A(t)$ is invertible and its eigenvalues are simple.

Then the eigenvalues and (unitary) eigenvectors of $A(t)$ can be chosen and numbered as functions with the same regularity; in particular $A(t)=P(t)diag(\lambda_i(t))P^{-1}(t)$ where the functions can be chosen regular.

Finally, $\sqrt{A(t)}=P(t)diag(\sqrt{\lambda_i(t)})P^{-1}(t)$ where the square roots are chosen s.t. the $(\sqrt{\lambda_i(t)})$'s are regular..